# my app is running on nexus emulator and it crashes on my mobile

Tags: android

my coding is

i get this error

```
03-14 14:45:06.178 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 E/Zygote: no v2
03-14 14:45:06.178 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0035
03-14 14:45:06.188 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 
03-14 14:45:06.188 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-14 14:45:06.388 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
03-14 14:45:06.588 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-14 14:45:07.119 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-14 14:45:07.269 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-14 14:45:07.399 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-14 14:45:07.499 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-14 14:45:07.609 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-14 14:45:07.719 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-14 14:45:07.819 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-14 14:45:07.929 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-14 14:45:08.019 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-14 14:45:08.120 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-14 14:45:08.120 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4-1/lib/arm
03-14 14:45:08.130 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
03-14 14:45:08.370 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
03-14 14:45:08.540 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f060055 (t=5 e=85) (error -75)
03-14 14:45:08.540 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-14 14:45:08.570 13719-13719/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4, PID: 13719
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4/com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                 at com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                 at com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                 at com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                              Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4:drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" (7f060055) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060055 a=-1 r=0x7f060055}
                                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4246)
                                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4153)
                                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3998)
                                                                                 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4244)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:591)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:202)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:198)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:194)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                 at com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

i didnt know how to solve this ..can anyone help me ..thanks in advance

Comment: *Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4:drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" (7f060055) is not a Drawable*  ?

Comment: share your XML also here

Comment: What is `ic_launcher_foreground`? Is it an image (jpg/png) or an XML file?

Answer (score -1):

A few things worth to try.

- Check your MainActivity's layout file.
- Make sure the activity is declared in the manifest
- Update all support lib to latest
- Clean and rebuild the app.

Comment: From the logcat: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.ashwinkumarn.e4:drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" (7f060055) is not a Drawable (color or path)`. In this case `@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground` is not a valid drawable.

Comment: how could it be compiled and run on simulator if ic_launcher_foreground is not a drawable?

Comment: The file `res/drawable/ic_launcher_foreground` would exist, and would therefore have an entry in `R.java`, so there would be no compilation issues. However, if the `ic_launcher_foreground` file is not what the inflater expects (an image, SVG or other drawable resource such as a `selector`), then this error would occur.

Comment: Try it for yourself by copying a layout file from `res/layout` to `res/drawable`, then referring to that file from `@drawable/`

Comment: it shouldn't have worked on simulator if ic_launcher_foreground is not a valid drawable, unless it is a bug in the simulator.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll withdraw my downvote for now then (if you can edit your answer to allow me to). I still think OP has not provided enough information for this question to be answerable though.

Comment: ic_foreground is just an background image for my app